# Abrir archivo con sudo en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito crear un archivo y escribirlo en modo root. Intenté con `f = open("hola.log", 'w+')` pero cuando lo ejecuto me sale: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`  Estoy trabajando con python3. Alguna idea?

Comment: TIenes derechos de administrador en la carpeta que contiene el archivo?

Comment: [Lee esta respuesta a una pregunta igual que la tuya pero en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499233/write-to-a-file-with-sudo-privileges-in-python) Dime si te soluciona el problema ?

Answer (score 0):

La solución era tan simple como ejecutar el script con sudo. Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

También puedes cambiar los permisos del fichero con el comando chmod:

`chmod 777 'hola.log'`

Indicando 777 otorgas todos los permisos a todos los usuarios, si quieres consultar cómo otorgar ciertos permisos solo a ciertos usuarios, consulta la documentación. [`man chmod`](https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)